# reusable section templates and variables

Tags: sectioning, context, templates, section-titles, variable

I'm looking for a way to declare a section (a chapter for instance) like that:

```tex
\startchapter[title={My first interview}][author={Jane Doe}, year={2022}]
…
\input knuth
\stopchapter


\startchapter[title={My second interview}][author={John Doe}, year={2023}]
…
\input knuth
\stopchapter
```

I'd like to generate the title page for each chapter that layout the title, but also the author, year and other defined `\structureuservariable`; some sort of template.

I did something like this using that:

```tex
\startsetups [titlepage]
    % Here comes some fancy layout with columns, layers and such
    \structureuservariable{author}
    
\stopsetups

\setuphead[chapter][placehead=hidden] % Chapter pages won’t have headers

\startchapter[title={My second interview}][author={John Doe}, year={2023}]

\setups{titlepage}

\input knuth
\stopchapter
```

I have several issues:

- I don't know how to retrieve the chapter title in my `titlepage` setup
- I'm not sure this is the right approach to "templating"

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you look for, give credits to Wolfgang, if not, blame me.

If you want to test for content, you can use `\doifsomething`.

```
\definedataset[chapter]

\startsetups[chapter:leftpage]
     \doglobal\increment\ChapterData
     \page[yes]
     \midaligned{\definedfont[Serif*default at 21pt]\WORD \datasetvariable{chapter}{\ChapterData}{title}}\blank[line]
     \midaligned{\definedfont[Serif*default at 14pt]\datasetvariable{chapter}{\ChapterData}{author}, \datasetvariable{chapter}{\ChapterData}{year}}\blank[2*line]
\stopsetups

\startsetups[chapter:savedata]
     \setdataset
         [chapter]
         [\ChapterData]
         [   title=\structurevariable{title},
              year=\structureuservariable{year},
            author=\structureuservariable{author}]
\stopsetups

\setuphead[chapter][
  page=,
  number=no,
  placehead=no,
  style={\WORD},
  location=none,
  indentnext=no,
  beforesection=\directsetup{chapter:leftpage},
  insidesection=\directsetup{chapter:savedata},
]


\starttext

\startchapter[title={My second interview}][author={John Doe}, year={2023}]

\input knuth
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image: output]

Comment: That looks like what I was looking for, thanks a lot to you and Wolfgang!